# Compare the heads of two files in bash

Tags: bash, shell, diff, head

I can do `diff filea fileb` to see the difference between files. I can also do `head -1 filea` to see the first line of filea or fileb.  How can I combine these commands to show the difference between the first line of filea and the first line of fileb?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If your shell supports [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst), try:

```
diff <(head -n 1 filea) <(head -n 1 fileb)
```

Comment: I had already seen the process substition command somewhere, but didn't know what it did. Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

If you are only comparing the first line of each file, maybe you care about word-level changes within the line, using `dwdiff`:

```
dwdiff <(head -n 1 filea) <(head -n 1 fileb)
```

`dwdiff` has some nice options, like `-c` to colorize the changed words.

Or, using `sed` instead of head:

```
dwdiff <(sed 1q filea) <(sed 1q fileb)
```

which the [manual for head](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/head-invocation.html) suggests is more portable than head, as the syntax for head has changed over time `head -1` vs `head -n 1`

Also, you could just eyeball the changes, with a bit less typing:

```
head -n1 -q filea fileb
```

which displays the two lines, one below the other, for easy visual comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if [ "`head -1 file1`" == "`head -1 file2`" ]; then echo "the same"; fi
```

Comment: Note that it would answer "the same" if file1 is an empty file (or not readable) and file2's first line is empty.

Comment: I did not say that this method is 'idiot proof' but if you quickly want to match the first line of two files...